# How can I refer to an as-variable inside a nested Gremlin traversal?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

In trying to write a traversal that matches only if there is not an existing edge from vertex Vo to vertex Vi (where the ID of Vi might not be known ahead of time, and so Vi has to be specified by a traversal).

I had this initial traversal:

```java
<A> GraphTraversal<A, Edge> addEdge(
  GraphTraversal<A, Vertex> traversalToVo,
  String viSelectKey
) {
  return traversalToVo.coalesce(
    __.outE("Manages").and(
      __.inV().as("inV").where("inV", P.neq(viSelectKey))
      // more conditions
    ),
    __addE("Manages").to(select(viSelectKey))
  );
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make `Vi` available inside the nested anonymous traversal; everything I've thought of results in the error

```
Neither the sideEffects, map, nor path has a Vi-key: WherePredicateStep(inV,neq(Vi))
```

I've debugged the call to `getScopeValue`, and in fact `Vi` is never defined when I get there.

Approaches I've tried to populate `Vi` include:

```java
// define "Vi" in the upstream part of the query
gts.addV(...).as("Vi").V(Vo).coalesce(...)

// modeled after "Long Traversals" recipe; variable not defined afterward
gt.V(Vo).sideEffect(viTraversal.asAdmin().clone().as("Vi")).coalesce(...)

// produces a Map, and I can't apply unfold() downstream inside predicate
gt.sideEffect(viTraversal.asAdmin().clone().group("Vi"))
```

As far as I can tell, this is the result of some scoping rule that detaches the nested anonymous traversals from the scope values; how do I bridge the gap so that an `as`-variable defined in the upstream part of the traversal can be referenced from inside coalesce-and-where?

Comment: maybe this helps https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/K3KiksRROlQ/m/GuKI5gu0AgAJ

Comment: @aran It doesn't account for the base requirement that this chain starts with an incoming fixed traversal that I need to capture and then operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version of this is very close to correct, however you didn't specify what `Vi` represents.  You can do this through the use of a mid-traversal V().  Here is how you would accomplish something like this on the modern graph:

```
g.V(2).as('Vi').V(1).coalesce(
  __.outE("Manages").and(
    __.inV().where(P.neq("Vi"))
  ),
  __.addE("Manages").to(select("Vi"))
);
```

In this example, I am specifying the vertex id, but you could use other Gremlin filter steps to get the desired result.

Comment: The first version _does_ specify `Vi` through `addV`. The `Vi` key is not available inside the predicate's scope.

Comment: There is no `Vi` or addV() in the first version that I based my answer on, so I'm not really sure to what you are referring.  The one that has an addV does not show enough of the query to understand what might be the issue.  The traversal I put in the answer was tested to work against Gremlin Server.

Comment: I'll clarify, thanks. Does it work with TinkerGraph?

Comment: Yes I have tested this against TInkerGraph in Gremlin Console

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems inefficient and icky, but it does work. I still don't know why I can access a `group` but not an `as`.

```java
traversalToVo.sideEffect(traversalToVi.asAdmin().clone().group("toV").by(id))
  .coalesce(
    __.outE("rel").and(
      __.inV().id().where(P.within("toV")).by().by(Column.keys),
      // other filters
    ),
    __.addE("rel").to(traversalToVi)
  )
```

Comment: I am confused by the issue here and the use of the sideEffect().  When you run a traversal like this does this work: g.V(Vi).as('Vi').V(Vo).both().select('Vi')

Comment: @bechbd _That_ one does, yes. What does not work is using `select('Vi')` inside the coalesce->and.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the issue here.  I have provided a working sample in the previous answer that has been tested against a TinkerGraph using the "modern" graph in the Gremlin Console.  It is the same syntax as your original query with the addition of specifying 'Vi'.  Your original query never specified anything with  'as('Vi')' so there is no way to select('Vi').  If I am misunderstanding,  please put the entire query including the missing traversalToVo  portion into the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: @bechbd Self-editing blindness; I had been through enough revisions I didn't realize the context that was missing from the question. Updating.

Comment: No problem.  However the issue with your original query still appears to be that there is no portion of that query shown where you set anything to an alias of 'Vi'.  e.g. g.V().limit(1).as('Vi') .  You are passing in the key from the parameter but what is setting that in the first portion of the query.  Without this my guess is that traversalToVo is using a reducing barrier step (e.g. fold(), max(), min(), group(), etc) which prevent you from using anything aliased later in the traversal as it has no way to know what the alias refers to.